# How do I align several buttons in the middle?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

```
<div class="button">

<p>
 <style>
a.button1 {
float: left;
height: 398px;
margin: 59px 0px 0px 17px;
background-image: url("i/about-button.gif");
text-indent: -9999px;
display: inline-block;
}

a#about-button {
width: 340px;
background-position: 0px 0px;}

a#about-button:hover {
background-position: 0px -796px;}

a#about-button:active {
background-position: 0px -398px;}</style>
<body>
<a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button" image></a>
</body>
</p>
</div>
```

Ok, I'm a noob at this so bear with me. I am trying to align my navigation buttons right in the center. That is, no matter how wide your window is, they will stay in the middle for the most part. Right now, they all align to the left.

I have a.button1, a.button2, a.button3 and a.button4. They are perfectly aligned to each other; I just need to figure out how to make them all move to the center.
Sorry but I haven't been able to find an answer in the other topics that would help me with my kind of code. HELP!

Comment: eeek, this HTML is quite wacky.  Before even going this far.. you really ought to run trough a couple novice tutorials.  there should not be `body` tags within a `p`  nor should there be `style` etc.. lots of other weirdness...

Answer (score 1):

You can align several things together in the middle by using something like this

In the Head:

```
<style>
.button {
    text-align:centre;
}
.button > * {
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

And at the point you want to centre the things:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button"></a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="button2" id="contact-button"></a>
</div>
```

And that will place those two links centre aligned together within the div `button`. All direct child elements of that div will be centred too.

By the way, your html should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.button1 {
float: left;
height: 398px;
margin: 59px 0px 0px 17px;
background-image: url("i/about-button.gif");
text-indent: -9999px;
display: inline-block;
}

a#about-button {
width: 340px;
background-position: 0px 0px;}

a#about-button:hover {
background-position: 0px -796px;}

a#about-button:active {
background-position: 0px -398px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button">
<p>
<a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button" image></a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, there's several things you need to understand:

1. You can't float the button left, and expect it to stay centered.
2. You don't need `<div><p><a>` - that extra markup just makes things complicated.
3. In order to center something in the window, set `text-align: center` either on the `body`, or else an element that is full-width (such as the div below).

Your styles, adjusted:

```
div.button {
    text-align: center;
}

a.button1 {
    height: 398px;
    margin: 59px auto 0px auto;
    background-image: url("i/about-button.gif");
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: inline-block;
}

a#about-button {
    width: 340px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

a#about-button:hover {
    background-position: 0px -796px;
}

a#about-button:active {
    background-position: 0px -398px;
}
```

Your HTML should only need to be like so:

```
<div class="button">
        <a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button" image></a>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Since you mentioned your nav *buttons*, I thought I'd show you what will work for multiple links as well:

First, this is all you need for HTML:

```
<div class="button">
        <a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button"></a>
        <a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button"></a>
        <a href="about.html" class="button1" id="about-button"></a>
</div>
```

And you'll need to modify your css slightly for your button, since it's VERY wide and tall.

Comment: THANKS so much, to both of you guys! This did the trick! I am taking a programming class and my project is due next week and I still have a long way to go! This really made my day! Thanks soooo much!!!